# Communication between applet and CGI in java

Tags: java, applet, cgi

I have applet with such start() code:

```
public void start() {
        try {
            URL cgiUrl = new URL("http://localhost:8080/cgi_lib/UsersCGI.exe?someText");
            URLConnection con = cgiUrl.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(out);
            dout.writeUTF("Hello");
            String receivedString = din.readUTF();
            this.out=receivedString;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And CGI written on java and compiled to .exe (using launch4j):

```
    public class UsersCGI {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
        }
    }
```

So, I have error:

> "java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 0"

at line

> String receivedString = din.readUTF();

What I did wrong?

Comment: There are a few problems with how you are sending the data, your cgi program needs to read from **stdin** (not args), and applets are ***dead***.

Comment: I added reading from standard input in CGI but it doesn't work. It even doesn't work if in CGI just print String. Maybe something wrong with hosting (I just put applet.class and CGi.exe in subfolder of web (It's Web project))?

Comment: PS. I know that applets have died but I must do this task.

Comment: PPS. for server I use Tomcat 7.